# Let a be a positive rational number. Let $A = \{ x\in\Bbb Q \mid x^2 < a \}$ . Show that $A$ is bounded in $\Bbb Q$

Tags: analysis

I need to prove the following:

> Let $a$ be a positive rational number.
>
> Let $A = \{ x\in\Bbb Q \mid x^2 < a \}$ .
>
> Show that $A$ is bounded in $\Bbb Q$

So I know I have to show that $A$ is bounded above and below in $\Bbb Q$. I have figured out that A is bounded above by $\sqrt(a)$ but I am unsure to prove that it is bounded below.

Answer (score 1):

Because a square root can be either positive or negative, when you have $x^2<a$ and you take the square root of both sides, you actually get two inequalities out.

$$\begin{align}
x^2 &< a \\
\implies\quad x<\sqrt{a} \;\;\;&\text{and}\;\;\; x>-\sqrt{a}\\
\implies\quad -\sqrt{a}< \;& x < \sqrt{a}
\end{align}$$

That gives you a lower bound.

Answer (score -1):

$A=[-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2]\cap \Bbb Q$